# Schemes defined by a collection of Plücker coordinates

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

If $C \subset {[n]\choose k}$ is any collection of $k$-element sets, we can define a scheme $$ W(C) = \bigcap_{S\notin C} \{V \in Gr(k,n) : p_S(V)=0\} \qquad \subseteq Gr(k,n), $$ where $p_S$ is the corresponding Plücker coordinate. Two well-known theorems about this construction are (1) any Schubert variety is of the form $W(C)$ [Hodge-Pedoe], and (2) if $W(C)$ is irreducible then $C$ is a matroid. (The converse does not hold.)

(Proof of #2: $C$ is a matroid iff each $\pi\cdot C$ has a unique Bruhat minimum, $\pi\in S_n$. One traces this to the fact that an irreducible variety has a unique open Białynicki-Birula stratum, for the circle $\pi\cdot{\check\rho}$.

> Where does this construction appear in the literature? <strike>I am convinced that</strike> I saw it in a paper by Neil White <strike>but have been unable to relocate it.</strike> :  The bracket ring of a combinatorial geometry. I, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 202 (1975), 79–95, where he assumes that $C$ is the set of bases of a matroid, without much need I can see. Has anyone else made use of it, especially without this assumption?

Warning: there is another (non-closed) subscheme
$$
GGMS(C) := W(C) \cap \bigcap_{S\in C} \{p_S \neq 0\}$$
called the Gel'fand-Goresky-MacPherson-Serganova stratum. In general $W(C)$ is not the closure of $GGMS(C)$. In particular, $W(C)$ is only empty when $C$ is, whereas $GGMS(C)$ is empty unless $C$ is a representable matroid.

Comment: By «$C$ is a matroid» you mean that it is the set of bases of a matroid?

Comment: Yes. $\   \ \ \ \ \ \      $